# How to purge package configuration file?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I try to install midori web browser,but this appears

```
sudo apt-get install midori
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
midori is already the newest version (0.5.11-ds1-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.8:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-38 linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up matlab-support (0.0.21) ...
No default Matlab path found. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package matlab-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 matlab-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

```
sudo apt-get remove matlab-suport
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package matlab-suport
```

I have tried to install matlab support,now I do not know how to get rid of this.It appears all the time.WHat should I try?

Comment: Try purging `matlab-support` from your system. You should find plenty of help with the search function of AskUbuntu

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Take a look at my edit please!

Comment: please fix your typo in the package name and try again. Besides to purge you would user the command purge with apt-get.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann yes,works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a package completely, you can use

```
apt-get purge packagename
```

In your case this would be

```
apt-get purge matlab-support
```